# Spot a bad linear regression fit from model output?

Tags: regression

How can I spot if, say, a simple, linear regression will adequately describe some causal relationship purely from the model's output (say, from the command `summary(lm( y ~x ))` in R), as opposed to from looking at QQ plots or residual plots? Is it possible? Perhaps something to do with the estimated variance?

Comment: There is the usual $R^2$ value which indicates how good the linear fit is. This will be a function of the estimated variance, so that might give a good idea.

Comment: Nothing in the usual output tells you anything about causal relationships. Causality is all in the design and substantive context and interpretation.

Comment: You cannot tell from that output whether the model is suitable or not. See the four data sets in the [Anscombe quartet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe's_quartet) which have identical output.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick Cox already commented, you can't. Here is a little example where I generate data according to a "causal" relationship between $y$ and $x$, and yet, because that relationship is noisy, the output neither gives you a statistically significant relationship nor an $R^2$ that differs perceptibly from zero.

```
n <- 100

beta <- 0.1
x <- runif(n)
u <- rnorm(n,sd=10)
y <- x*beta + u
```

[image]

```
> summary(lm(y~x))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-23.9617  -6.8501  -0.9274   8.0018  28.7454 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   -2.134      2.155   -0.99    0.324
x              2.383      3.608    0.66    0.511

Residual standard error: 10.83 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.004431,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.005728 
F-statistic: 0.4361 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.5105
```